# common code elimination will this double check be optimised out when being JITed?

Tags: java

Find the following code in `java.util.concurrent.AbstractQueuedSynchronzier`

```
if (((h = head) != null && (s = h.next) != null &&
     s.prev == head && (st = s.thread) != null) ||
    ((h = head) != null && (s = h.next) != null &&
     s.prev == head && (st = s.thread) != null ))
    return st;
```

The original intentions seems to check twice to ensure the condition is met.

My question is: when this piece of code hit JIT, will it be optimised out since the two check looks exactly the same ?

Comment: as `s = h.next` and `st = s.thread` are assignments in there it´s probably not the same, especially, with whatever `h` is, the `h.next` call could make the second statement a completly different one, as `s` would be different.

Comment: `h` and `s` are both `java.​util.​concurrent.​locks.​AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#Node` (for information) descibe as _Wait queue node class._

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: when this piece of code hit JIT, will it be optimised out since the two check looks exactly the same ?

If we assume that the fields referenced in that long expression are not `volatile`, then, since the there are no assignments to the fields in the expression, the JIT compiler is allowed to assume that nothing else will change them.  That means that it *is allowed* to optimize away the second memory reads.

Whether the JIT compiler actually does that is liable to be platform specific; i.e. it depends on compiler versions, etcetera.